# Going through a list and adding its individual values to a statement

Tags: c#, .net, windows

For each of the int's in a list (mylist) I would like the following to be executed:

e.g.

```
// Add series and points
ramChart.Series["RAM"].Points.AddY(mylist[0]);
ramChart.Series["RAM"].Points.AddY(mylist[1]);
ramChart.Series["RAM"].Points.AddY(mylist[2]);
```

and so on until there it has gone through all of the list values

Comment: There's a loop for that.

Comment: friendly advice: you should take some courses to brush up on the basics before drawing charts :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something as simple as:

```
foreach(var i in mylist)
{
    ramChart.Series["RAM"].Points.AddY(i);
}
```

Comment: Should have tried that, didnt assume it would be that easyt with lists

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
for (i=0 .. mylist.size(){
    ramChart.Series["RAM"].Points.AddY(mylist[i]);
}
```

perhaps use an iterator, but I dont really know c# syntax

edit: you can speed this process up by doing list concatenation instead of adding elements one by one